# How do you get the complexity of an sequence alignment algorithm?

Tags: algorithm

```
void opt(int i , int j )
{
  if(i == m)
    opt = 2( n - j);
  else if(j == n)
    opt = 2( m - i);
  else{
    if(x[i] == x[j])
     penalty = 0;
    else
     penalty = 1;
   opt = min(opt(i+1,j+1) + penalty, opt(i+1,j)+2, opt(i, j+1)+2);
  }
}
```

Why is the complexity of this algorithm 3^n ?

Analyze the time complexity of Algorithm opt.

Comment: The name of the function `opt()` is used as the name of a variable inside the function. I guess it's a typo.

Comment: thank you feedback, I want to know the ignition.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify how are you calling this function first. 
Regarding the analysis of Big O, you can get it by drawing the recursion tree. You can do it for small `n` samples and you will notice that  the height of the tree is `n`. Now, you can notice that for each instance of the function you call the same function 3 times again, so you have a tree that expands by a factor of 3 exponentially. Hence your complexity is `O(3^n)`.

**Bonus: Analogy with Fibonacci**

Check the basic (withot memoization) recusrive version of the Fibonacci algorithm and you will see the similar structure except for the fact that 2 calls are done each time, and hence the complexity is `O(2^n)`.